# How do you check the integrity of a VHD without using Powershell or Hyper-V Manager?

Tags: backup, powershell, vhd, data-integrity, paragon

I'm running Windows 10 Home, so I cannot enable Hyper-V manager nor use Powershell cmdlets like `test-vhd`. I used Paragon Hard Disk Manager 16 to create a backup image of my HD in .vhd format, and I'd like to be able to check the integrity of it to make sure the backup didn't get corrupted.

I cannot mount the VHD because it has the same disk signature as my current boot drive (which makes sense, since it's a clone of it). Any suggestions of how to check the integrity of this VHD?

Comment: Mount it on a different PC?

Comment: And for those of us without the luxury of regular access to multiple PC's? I find it hard to believe there isn't some simple tool, downloads or otherwise, to just check the integrity of a HDV.

Answer (score 1):

A virtual hard disk (.vhd) does not have any integrity checks by itself. It is merely opaque binary data + some header/footer. Only the header/footer have checksums.

So to check whether the virtual hard disk is intact you need to do the same thing you would do on a real hard drive: Run the filesystem-specific check program on each filesystem present.

`Test-VHD` doesn’t perform checks like this anyway.

Hyper-V isn’t the only software that supports the VHD format. [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) does, too! So you can just attach the backup to a Windows VM and check it like a regular hard disk.

Note that Windows will modify most filesystems it mounts.

Comment: How would Windows (which presumably includes any Windows VM) modify it? Since Windows recently expanded WSL to support full Ubuntu VMs, I could mount it through a Linux program. Does that open up my options any more? Would that be a less destructive option?

Comment: When mounting read/write, the dirty flag is set. Some timestamps may also be updated. // I doubt you could get WSL to mount a VHD, much less Linux.